Does $Z(f) \cap Z(g) = \emptyset$ implies $\gcd(f,g) = 1$?
If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are in $\mathbb{F}[x]$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is a field. Let us assume that $Z(f) = \{x \in \overline {\mathbb{F}} : f(x) = 0\}$, where $\overline{\mathbb{F}}$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}$. Does $Z(f) \cap Z(g) = \emptyset$  imply  $\gcd(f,g) = 1$?
Does $Z(f) \cap Z(g) = \emptyset$ always imply  $\gcd(f,g) = 1$?
If $Z(f) \cap Z(g) = \emptyset$, then if we go to the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}$. Now, if $h$ is a polynomial with a positive degree and is a common factor of $f,g$. Then, in the algebraic closure field, this $h(x) =  \displaystyle \prod_{\alpha \in Z(f) ~\text{or}~ \alpha \in Z(g)}(x - \alpha)$. Now, to be a common factor, at least one $\alpha \in Z(f) \cap Z(g)$ exists, which is impossible.
Is this proof okay, or is something wrong with this?

Take $f(x)=x^2+1=g(x)$  over $\mathbb R$.

Well, your definition of $Z$ is unclear.  I took it to mean ${x\in \mathbb F,|,f(x)=0}$ but perhaps you meant  ${x\in \overline {\mathbb F},|,f(x)=0}$

No, I am considering $Z(f)$ in the splitting field.

That's not clear from your post.  But, sure.  any root of the gcd would be a common zero in the algebriac closure.

Yes, sorry for that. I just updated that.
